# Change multiple Matrix elements by Index Vectors

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
myMatrix <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

and I want to change particular values

```
myMatrix[1,1] <- 1
myMatrix[2,3] <- 1
myMatrix[4,4] <- 1

myMatrix

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

How can I do this efficient/elegantly if I have two vectors containing the row and column indexes:

```
rowIndexes <- c(1,2,4)
colIndexes <- c(1,3,4)
```

The assigned value is constant (in this case `1`).

I know how to do it with a `for`-loop, but this feels inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `cbind` the row/column index, subset the `myMatrix` and assign values to 1

```
myMatrix[cbind(rowIndexes, colIndexes)] <- 1
myMatrix
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: you're awesome.